# ASP.NET and Entity Framework Check The Result is Empty Or Not

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Using code like this:

```
AppEntities data = new AppEntities();
var result = data.GIS_CONTRACTOR_TEST.Where(x => x.CONTRACTORNAME == txtSearch.Text);
GridView1.DataSource = result.ToList();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I am able to filter data based on the text box. now my question is How I can check if the `result` **is empty or not**? I mean if I want to send a message to user that there is not such a value in the database? how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (result == null || result.ToList().Count == 0)
{
  // Display message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean outside asking the list whether it has a length of 0? WHich would be the obvious thing to do?